# How are Code Aurora source archives organized?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, repo

I hit up Code Aurora while trying to find the kernel sources for Qualcomm MSM devices. The listing at [Code Aurora](https://source.codeaurora.org/) sources is overwhelming. I couldn't spot any documentation explaining what is what. What are all these projects? What's the naming convention followed? What are the grayed out items, e.g. `quic/la`? Do all these projects correspond to individual git repositories? Can anyone point to any source that explains me the archive structure?

Answer (score 2):

Now here's what I do know of the source structure.

Under [`quic/la`](https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la) all the git projects that are used for running Android on MSMs are hosted.

There are various versions of kernel git projects:

- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.10/
- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.14/
- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-3.18/
- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-4.4/
- https://source.codeaurora.org/quic/la/kernel/msm-4.9/

Now, as we all know form press that there are various snapdragons. Not all snapdragons may be supported on each kernel version.

I would recommend listing the tags for each kernel and try and find if the chip of your interest is supported there, this is the tedious part.

- By looking at the device tree files you may be able to determine if your chip is in that kernel tree.
- defconfig files you may find supported chips.

Comment: Do you know, how the tag and branch names work? What do they mean, when are they released, who needs them and for what?

Answer (score 1):

`la` is for android, `le` for embedded and I believe `lc` is for chromium.